# iOS Gesture not detected due to accessibility settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

An app I am developing requires a three-point swipe gesture.

I have successfully implemented this using a `UIGestureRecognizer` and it works fine for the most part.

However, if you switch the device Zoom accessibility setting on (Settings > General > Accessibility > Zoom) this stops the gesture from being recognized.

The Zoom function uses various three-point gestures to operate, so I can understand this superseding my app gesture.

However, does anyone know how I can determine if the Zoom setting is turned on (or the zoom accessibility gesture performed) so I can at least advise the user that the gesture will not be recognized?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` or did you use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and set the `numberOfTouchesRequired` property to three?

Comment: I used a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with `numberOfTouchesRequired` set to three

Comment: You could detect both three-finger and four-finger swipes...

Comment: Thanks tc. Unfortunately the client will not allow that... it's a very specific UI requirement for the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS 5, take a look at `UIAccessibilityRegisterGestureConflictWithZoom()`. While it doesn't tell you if Zoom is enabled, it will let your users know when there's a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an if statement to check if the user has accessability enabled then if they do, make your app do a four finger swipe.

```
if (isAccessabilityElement)
```

? have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this property is to indicate that a control is accessible for users with disabilities. (All standard UIKit controls return YES by default for example). Unfortunately this does not tell me if a user has accessibility settings turned on.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to find out is zoom set or not set in UIScrollView delegate methods
but u can try using UIPinchGestureREcognizer in addition to swipe gesture recognizer.
For Further information you can check out in apple's developer documentation.